# Order when linking object files and static libraries

Tags: c++, linker

I have created 2 object files `hello.o` and `hi.o`, each containing a function with the same name, respectively. Also, `greetings.h` was created containing the function prototypes of the two object files.

When I link these two object files with `main.o` in any order, the process succeeds and I get a.out. But if you make a static library from the `hello.o` and `hi.o` files, then the linking succeeds only in the order `g++ main.o glib.a`.

As I understand it, the order should be from the file that declares to the file that contains the definition, but when linking object files alone, it doesn't work. What is the difference between linking a library  and object files, and only object files?

Example:

Source code:

```
greetings.hpp
```

```
#ifndef GREETINGS_HPP
#define GREETINGS_HPP

void hello();
void hi();

#endif
```

```
hello.cpp
```

```
#include <iostream>

void hello() {
    std::cout << "Hello!" << std::endl;
}
```

```
hi.cpp
```

```
#include <iostream>

void hi() {
    std::cout << "Hi!" << std::endl;
}
```

```
main.cpp
```

```
#include "greetings.hpp"

int main () {
    hello();
    hi();
    return 0;
}
```

Actions:

```
ar -src glib.a hello.o hi.o
```

```
g++ glib.a main.o
```

Error:

```
main.o: In function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0x5): undefined reference to `hello()'
main.cpp:(.text+0xa): undefined reference to `hi()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: Linking object files keeps all the symbols (possibly dead stripping unneeded ones later).  Linking library files (which is a collection of object files) only uses the library objects files needed in order to resolve unresolved symbols.  That's why circular dependencies between libraries can be annoying, necessitating specifying them multiple times — as a workaround.

Comment: Show the smallest code you can come up with that shows the problem. In particular, functions having the same name isn’t a problem if they have different signatures.

Comment: Uisng the command `g++ glib.a main.o` the linker traverses `glib.a` and decides that there's nothing useful at this moment, so dismisses it all. Then it continues with `main.o` where it finds some "undefined references" to those defined in the dismissed lib. Working with g++ and libs the order matters absolutely.

Comment: Object files first, followed by libraries.